# Why is ruby on rails testing super slow in linux?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux

I have reviewed blogpost from 2008 to date. I have Inherited a ruby ​​on rails project for which I need to increase the test code.

I work on a laptop asus computer with an 8gen cpu i7U with 16gb ram and a 512gb ssd.

Initially I was running ubuntu 19.10, when I started the project and with about 1200 tests. it takes more than 1hr to run. Whereas on a 2015 macbook pro with 8gb of ram and an hdd, it takes only 2-3 min.

The log / test.log does not report errors, the tests do not hang, but waiting too long is not efficient, especially when i'll be increasing the number of tests.
So I Uninstall ubuntu, wipe off the ssd, install solus, arch and ubuntu, with the same setup for all through asdf as version manager and in no distro the time is less than 1hr.

Does anyone know why this happens in linux? The mac setup is also through asdf and it is fast enough.

Comment: It must be something OS related, like a system library. Rails had some bcrypt issues in the past. This blog post from 2012 shows a fix for that specific problem and also a way to profile your test suite using Google's Perftools: [Tests Still Slow? Might be bcrypt!](https://collectiveidea.com/blog/archives/2012/11/12/tests-oddly-slow-might-be-bcrypt)

Comment: the ruby version is the same on both platforms ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not an answerable practical programming question.

Comment: Of course i am aware both os are different, but ruby is said to be os agnostic. It is a programming question since i know a bunch of people affected by this same issue that didn't dare to question just because of people like max. We are a community and among us somebody may know more low level things than others. Stefan thank you i'll check that. And Gipsh yes they are using ruby 2.6.5 with rails 6

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the specifics of the codebase or the tests, this question is equivalent to "how long is a piece of string."

There are many differences between linux and macOS. Cryptographic libraries may have different defaults.  Memory limits for threads will be different.  Memory limits for processors may be different.

Unless you can isolate specific tests which are wildly different and extrapolate from there, it's almost certainly going to come down to OS-level differences.

Comment: This is true, but its also more of a comment then an actual answer.

Comment: Thank you but it is a more generalized problem, i work for a company of software development and we many languages. Casually the only one giving us problems in linux is ruby when the code base grows. I can't share code since it is from a client. But it also wouldn't help, not all our projects use the same gems or the same ruby version. But they all fail with ruby test. So this means macos has monopolize the market for ruby and linux is doing nothing???